# Error while compiling openCL in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, makefile, opencl

I'm trying to compile a Rodinia application on Ubuntu but there is a strange error during compiling:

```
   cd ../../common/simple-opencl && make -f Makefile_TMP
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mart/git/rodinia-2.4/common/simple-opencl'
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -I/home/mart/git/rodinia-2.4/common/simple-opencl/inc - I/usr/local/cuda/include -c simpleCL.c
   In file included from simpleCL.c:28:0:
   simpleCL.h:37:19: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
    #include <CL/cl.h>
                   ^
   compilation terminated.
   make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mart/git/rodinia-2.4/common/simple-opencl'
   make: *** [../../common/simple-opencl/simpleCL.o] Error 2
```

The makefiles assign the correct path for the CL, in fact in the main.c there is no compilation error.
The problem should be in the MakeFale_TMP in AMDAPPSDKROOT variable that is not correctly set (I think...).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does CL/cl.h exist and where? Also at least in your pasted output there seems to be an extra space between - and I/usr/local/cuda/include

Comment: Make sure that your include folder is pointing to the directory that houses /CL instead of pointing to the folder that houses /CL/cl.h.

Comment: May this be the reason: - I/usr/local/cuda/include instead of -I/usr/local/cuda/include ?